# Git: Failed to erase credential: Element not found tried all other solutions

Tags: git, github, credentials, git-extensions

Using git extensionas & the git bash, I have cloned my github repo.

Now when I got to do the first push it asks for meuname and password then gives the error

```
Failed to erase credential: Element not found
Authentication failed
```

I have seen this issue in other questions and forums - so far nothing has worked;
I have:

- reverted Git from 1.8.3 to 1.8.2
- deleted and re-created my credentials in windows credential manager
- ran push from bash add entered credentials in bash instead of password gate
- uninstalled git extensions & git, deleted local repo and re-installed and cloned from scratch

Im using https but I also have tried using ssh  -  This worked of course, but I would prefer to use HTTPS, are there any other possible solutions to this issue out there?

Thanks

Comment: I'm in the same boat - I've tried all those options and get the same error every time.  I've also tried working with git-credential-winstore, and going to Git 1.8.4.

Comment: @CSJ I think I just stuck with using SSH :(

Comment: I did the same thing.  It sucks, because the [Visual Studio Git Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) don't support SSH (yet).

Answer (score 2):

I got the same message. I was ask by the winstore to type login, user and password.

The password I copied direct from the Firefox Password Manger.

And than I got the fail message.

But than I tried it again and type the password by hand, and it worked.

So I suggest you double check the login data you use. May be there is the problem.